# Can anyone advise on a guide to the usage of "enote"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, terminology, mathematics

I am looking to use "enote" in a mathematical description where the symbol occurs before the concept, and denote seems inappropriate. (I suppose with rewriting this can be overcome, but that's a different matter which doesn't help with my query.) I learned this usage somewhere, many years ago, but am unable to find a web resource on the usage of enote to check my recollection. Any guidance is welcome.

Edit #1: Although I don't have access to a library right now, I note that some other people have concerns about certain usages of denote (possibly those where one could correctly use enote?!)

http://www.waywordradio.org/discussion/topics/going-against-convention-while-writing-in-your-field-denote-by/

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've ever seen the word "enote" is as an internet term for "electronic note".

I think you can still use denote when the symbol occurs before the concept; in fact, that's pretty much what the word is *for*. Consider the example given when you google it.

> be a sign of; indicate.

or

> stand as a name or symbol for.

If the concept occurred before the symbol, *that's* when denote would be inappropriate. With the usage you've described, it seems like the logical choice: the symbol **denotes** the concept, and the concept is **denoted by** the symbol.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is about the usage of enote.

Comment: My answer is basically longhand for "There is no usage of enote unless you mean an electronic note and are okay using slang terms."

Comment: I suppose my question would then be "Why are you looking to use a word that as far as I can tell doesn't exist when you already have one which serves the purpose you needed a word for?"

Comment: I have seen enote used in mathematical settings in the past, here's one:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112532/do-best-lower-approximations-of-a-quadratic-irrational-always-form-a-linear-recu/117597#117597
 and it is not used to mean electronic note. It is a very uncommon usage, but isn't that what makes language flexible and interesting?

Comment: The problem with making language more flexible and interesting than the "rules" advise is that you end up saying things where nobody knows what you mean. :P Honestly if I had read that post outside the context of this question I'd have assumed Ewan made a typo. I have been able to find literally nothing supporting "enote" as a mathematical term.

Comment: I appreciate your point. This is why I am looking for someone to direct me to a standard reference, preferably one from a discipline such as logic, mathematics or physics. I think if enote was more different to the more common denote, it would be a lot easier to find and I wouldn't be here asking the question.

Comment: Going by the fact that he said it only in that one place (where I think "denote" would fit) and also misspelled "eventually" in his original post, I think he just made a spelling mistake to be honest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37320/discussion-between-jason-whyte-and-john-clifford).